# How can i Converting from char to string and transferring it to a two-dimensional matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream

I have a `kelimeler.txt` file.

```
101,Tarkan,E,1,22,1,1,0 
102,Mustafa,E,2,54,0,0,1
103,Seher,K,2,65,0,1,0
104,Ali,E,1,88,0,1,0
105,Ahmet,E,3,12,1,0,0
106,Osman,E,5,2,0,0,0
107,Remziye,K,3,63,0,0,1
108,Ayse,K,1,10,0,0,0
109,Esma,K,2,25,0,0,0
110,Mahmut,E,1,35,0,0,0
111,Rıza,E,2,6,0,0,0
112,Sultan,K,4,14,0,0,0
113,Selim,E,1,85,0,1,0
114,Bekir,E,3,42,0,0,0
115,Salih,E,5,81,1,1,1
116,Fatma,K,2,25,0,1,0
117,Aliye,K,2,3,0,0,0
118,Yilmaz,E,1,69,0,1,0
119,Omer,E,2,93,1,0,1
120,Ibrahim,E,1,68,0,0,0
121,Azra,K,5,58,0,0,0
122,Meryem,K,1,15,0,0,0
123,Berk,E,2,80,0,0,0
124,Emre,E,3,60,1,1,0
125,Enes,E,2,42,1,0,0
126,Cemre,K,3,72,0,0,1
127,Burak,E,3,66,0,1,0
128,Nalan,K,4,45,0,0,0
129,Yusuf,E,5,41,0,0,0
130,Sait,E,5,50,0,0,0
131,Mehmet,E,2,30,0,0,0
132,Burcu,K,4,75,0,1,0
133,Elif,K,4,21,1,0,1
134,Zeynep,K,2,32,1,0,0
135,Aydin,E,2,33,1,0,0
136,Zeliha,K,3,87,0,1,0
137,Umut,E,1,28,0,0,0
138,Dogan,E,2,18,0,0,0
139,Ela,K,3,36,0,0,0
140,Zehra,K,4,24,0,0,0
141,Recep,E,4,46,1,1,0
142,Halil,E,5,18,0,0,0
143,Irmak,K,4,39,0,0,1
144,Fadime,K,3,52,0,0,0
145,Yagmur,K,3,19,0,0,0
146,Busra,K,2,61,0,0,0
147,Ozkan,E,3,40,0,0,0
148,Tarik,E,1,37,1,0,0
149,Nesrin,K,1,20,0,0,0
150,Cenk,E,3,34,1,0,1
```

I have to separate the elements in this file from commas and transfer them to a two dimensional matrix.
First i read the file and equaled a value. Then i converted to string value from char array. Then i seperated from commans with strtok function. Then i created a for loop. But its not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;

void ReadFileFunc(){
    ifstream readFile("kisiler.txt"); 
    
    string cumle = "";
    string kelime = "";
    string word = "";
    while(readFile >> cumle){
        
        kelime += cumle;
        kelime+="\n";
        //cout<<"Aktarildi"<<endl;
    }
int n = kelime.length();

char kelime_array[n+1];
strcpy(kelime_array,kelime.c_str());
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
    cout << kelime_array[i];
}

//cout << kelime<<"\n \n";
cout << endl;

string a[50][8];
char *point;
int sayi = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
point = strtok(kelime_array,",");
while (point!=NULL){
    cout  << " ";
    for(i = 0 ; i<50 ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<8; j++){
            a[i][j] = point ;
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            point = strtok(NULL,",");
        }
    }
}

    cout << a[0][1] ; // I tried but its not working

    readFile.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    ReadFileFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Escape the [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does and then [stop directly including it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Don't use `strtok`, as it modifies the string.  Consider using `std::getline(readFile, ',')`

Comment: Why do you need a 2d matrix?  I recommend creating a struct (or class) that models one record (line of input), then use `std::vector` of that class.